# Pandas groupby month output is incorrect

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a weird problem with `groupby` in Pandas. I am trying to group all the dates from the same month of a year to calculate the monthly average.

Dataframe:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

       Date      I1      I2      I3      I4      I5      I6
0   2014-01-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
1   2014-02-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2   2014-03-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
3   2014-04-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
4   2014-05-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
5   2014-06-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
6   2014-07-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
7   2014-08-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
8   2014-09-09  0.182   0.182   0.202   0.204   0.352   0.326
9   2014-10-09  4.818   4.840   4.852   4.834   4.498   4.663
10  2014-11-09  2.282   2.309   2.144   2.141   1.982   2.227
11  2014-12-09  5.179   5.212   5.183   5.175   4.713   5.028
...
```

Start date is from 1st Sep 2014. The format in this dataframe is `YYYY/DD/MM`.

I then applied `groupby` using `PeriodIndex` to find the monthly average of each `I#`.

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq="M"))[['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6']].mean()

           I1          I2         I3           I4         I5          I6
Date                        
2014-01 3.109500    3.122500    2.880750    2.890500    1.970500    1.948250
2014-02 3.499750    3.526000    3.108500    3.111750    1.944000    1.938250
2014-03 3.928750    3.963500    3.420250    3.428250    3.410250    3.339500
2014-04 2.320250    2.336250    2.090250    2.097250    2.074750    1.988500
2014-05 3.159250    3.183000    2.686000    2.688500    2.730250    2.703500
2014-06 2.679750    2.708500    2.472500    2.478000    2.416500    2.363750
2014-07 3.295000    3.362000    2.802750    2.800000    2.858750    2.982250
2014-08 3.511500    3.542500    3.155500    3.160500    1.981000    1.982000
2014-09 4.616364    4.633545    4.445273    4.451091    4.036864    4.102955
2014-10 3.917043    3.945261    3.466478    3.471217    3.904087    3.973522
```

`df1` show `2014-01` which there is no data on this particular month in my original `df`.

I think the `groupby` is grouping it due to the format of the `date`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Edit:

I think there is a misunderstanding to this question. My main issue lies with `groupby` function not grouping properly. In the output dataframe, you can see that there is an average for the month of `2014-01` which is Jan 2014. This should NOT appear at all as there is no data for Jan 2014. The first data starts in Sep 2014. The output should start with Sep 2014 month average onwards.

Edit 2:

Sorting date after `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

```
df = df.sort_values(by="Date")

        Date    I1       I2      I3      I4      I5      I6
0   2014-01-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
30  2014-01-10  5.962   5.966   5.551   5.558   5.399   5.525
61  2014-01-11  3.711   3.745   3.395   3.409   0.007   0.008
91  2014-01-12  2.765   2.779   2.577   2.595   2.476   2.260
1   2014-02-09  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
31  2014-02-10  4.078   4.107   3.800   3.797   3.588   3.893
62  2014-02-11  5.183   5.235   4.623   4.623   0.000   0.000
92  2014-02-12  4.738   4.762   4.011   4.027   4.188   3.860
...
```

Comment: Can you try `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)` ?

Comment: Or `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m')`

Comment: Try:  `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y/%d/%m')` instead at the beginning.  Or now, if already converted once, try the one jezrael mentioned.

Comment: `My main issue lies with groupby function not grouping the properly.` Unfortunately `groupby` working properly. But problem is in converting datetimes.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for looking at this. I have edited my post to clarify on the issue at hand. I did try everyone suggestion and somehow I am getting `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 3`. That said, I used these codes at the start of my program (it ran without error) but the `groupby` is still not functioning as what I want (refer to my edit feedback).

Comment: @jezrael thanks for your feedback. The dtypes of the `date` column before the `groupby` is `datetime64[ns]`. Do you mean that the `datetime64[ns]` date formatting is incorrect which result in this output?

Comment: I think it is incorrect parsed to datetimes, so get non exist `2014-01` If sorting values after `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` what is first value?

Comment: @jezrael please see my edit 2. Weird, the dates are sorted in a mess. Is this due to the formatting of the datetime?

Comment: do you try solutions in comments? first and second comment?

Comment: @jezrael I did tried both. First comment return the same result as `edit 2`. Second comment return error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  00:00:00`. Note that I ran both lines in a new `df` input, meaning I run it immediately after loading my `csv` into the `df`.